# Jquery No Conflict Inline

Tags: javascript, frameworks, onclick, jquery

Is there a way to add Jquery No Conflict at an inline level? With something like this as an example:

`<a href="javascriot:void(0)" onclick="$('body').html('<h1>Hello World!</h1>');">
Click Me!
</a>`

I keep running into conflict problems with other frameworks I have installed and it's something so simple I don't really want to add an onclick event for it. So how can I add a jquery no conflict clause to an inline onclick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `jQuery()` instead of `$()`

```
<a href="javascriot:void(0)" onclick="jQuery('body').html('<h1>Hello World!</h1>');"> Click Me! </a>
```

This way you avoid any conflicts of the value of `$`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="jQuery('body').html('<h1>Hello World!</h1>');"> Click Me!</a>
```

You really should be setting your event handlers through jQuery though. Using the `onclick` attribute is considered bad practice these days.

Also, if you want to use `jQuery.noConflict();` you should set it on page load.